Passing steps as parameters
My pipleine.yaml extends another template.yaml. There is a parameter prePlanSteps available in the template to allow me to add steps to the master.
My test script is simply:
echo region = ${{ env.region }}

This works if I put it directly as an inline step. However it fails if I try to pass the same code to the prePlanSteps parameter:
Unrecognized value: 'env'.

I've obviously got to pass this in a particular format/syntax to get it to resolve at the right time/place, but I can't work out how.
template.yaml:
parameters:
- name: envList
  type: object
- name: prePlanSteps
  type: stepList
  default: []

  - ${{ each env in parameters.envList }}:
    - stage: "${{ env.name }}Build"
      variables:
      jobs:
      - job: 'Plan'
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo region = ${{ env.region }}

          - ${{ parameters.prePlanSteps }}

pipeline.yaml:
 extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    envList:
      - name: dev
        region: myRegion
    prePlanSteps:
      - bash: |
          echo region = ${{ env.region }}
        displayName: preplansteps_test
        name: preplansteps_test


Hi @SiBush, Thx for reaching out to the subcommunity of Azure DevOps. Based on your YAML definitions, the ${{ env.region }} expression is not recognized until the template expression ${{each env}} in template.yaml is expanded. However, your current pipeline was trying to pass ${{ env.region }} before template expansion.
From outside the template, the pipeline couldn't recognize the ${{ env.region }} expression to be passed, since it was not yet processed.

With those being said,  the answer below by Shamrai Aleksander should work it around. Hope your query in this post can be resolved. Thx again for the sharing and have a lovely weekend.

It looks like it is trying to find your variable pipeline.yaml during compilation before extending. You may switch to variables and pass them to the template:
template
parameters:
- name: envList
  type: object
- name: prePlanSteps
  type: stepList
  default: []

stages:
  - ${{ each env in parameters.envList }}:
    - stage: "${{ env.name }}Build"
      variables:
      - name: my.env
        value: ${{ env.name }}
      - name: my.region
        value: ${{ env.region }}
      jobs:
      - job: 'Plan'
        steps:
        - bash: |
            echo region = ${{ env.region }}
        - ${{parameters.prePlanSteps}}

pipeline
extends:
  template: template.yml
  parameters:
    envList:
    - name: dev
      region: devreg
    - name: test
      region: testreg
    prePlanSteps:
      - bash: |
          echo extented region = $(my.region)
          echo extented env = $(my.env)
        displayName: preplansteps_test
        name: preplansteps_test


Based on your YAML definitions, the ${{ env.region }} expression is not recognized until the template expression ${{each env}} in template.yaml is expanded. However, your current pipeline was trying to pass ${{ env.region }} before template expansion.
From outside the template, the pipeline couldn't recognize the ${{ env.region }} expression to be passed, since it was not yet processed.
The answer below by Shamrai Aleksander could work it around, because from outside the template, it passed variables in macro syntax which got processed during pipeline runtime and didn't require the pipeline to recognize the expression before template expansion.
You may find more details in this document to help us Understand variable syntax.
